# Parsing Json in scala with extending java class

Tags: scala, fasterxml

I have a java class as below

```
public class JobConfig implements Serializable {
private String appName;
//some other params
public JobConfig() {
}
// getters setters
```

I am trying to extend the above java class in scala

```
class CsvJobConfig extends JobConfig(){
var delimiter =null
//other attributes
```

Now in main class am trying to parse a json and assign it back to CsvJobConfig .

```
val is = fileReader.getInputStreamFor(configFileName, configPath, spark)
var jobConfigJson = IOUtils.toString(is, Charset.defaultCharset.name)
val mapper = new ObjectMapper
val config = mapper.readValue(jobConfigJson, classOf[CsvJobConfig]).asInstanceOf[CsvJobConfig]
```

Below is the sample json am trying to parse

```
{
"appName":"abc",
"delimiter": "\\|\\|"
}
```

Although it works fine when tried from java , its giving me below error in scala

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "delimiter" (class CsvJobConfig), not marked as ignorable (1 known properties:  ["appName"])
 "[truncated 405 chars]; line: 29, column: 17] (through reference chain: CsvJobConfig["delimiter"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:52)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:839)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1045)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1330)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726)
    at com.mastercard.dw.etl.spark.FlatFileProcessor$.delayedEndpoint$com$mastercard$dw$etl$spark$FlatFileProcessor$1(FlatFileProcessor.scala:30)
    at com.mastercard.dw.etl.spark.FlatFileProcessor$delayedInit$body.apply(FlatFileProcessor.scala:11)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
```

Comment: Why not using a **Scala** library like **circe**, **uJson**, **play-json**, etc? This also would allow you to have idiomatic code like using an immutable case class instead of having unnecessary `vars`.

Comment: I will surely try , any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure which pointers you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectMapper has to be configured to not to FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES refer below code and also assign type of the variable in the scala class.

```
class CsvJobConfig extends JobConfig {
  var delimiter: String = null
}

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
val config: CsvJobConfig = mapper.readValue("{\"appName\":\"abc\", \"delimiter\": \"\\\\|\\\\|\"}", classOf[CsvJobConfig])
println(config)
println(config.delimiter)
```

Comment: thanks , i added the setter methods and its no more unknownproperties.it worked

Comment: Sure, maybe you could accept the answer if it worked. :)

Comment: adding the mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
 and having a case class worked

Answer (score 0):

Worth trying with

```
var delimiter: String = null
```

In your code, the type of the variable delimiter is of Null Type, which may cause this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Adding mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
and having a case class solved the issue.
Also Adding the setter methods manually in the scala class can solve the issue.